# jquery li > checkbox parent

Tags: jquery

I've been researching in stackoverflow and api.jquery for longer than 1h and I decided to ask because there is something I am missing here and I don't know what is it.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" **checked**>
        FIRST
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        SECOND
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox">
        THIRD
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is more or less, like that. I have let the First input 'checked' by default for the test. I would like to relate the checkbox with its closest `li` (for future Remove-function). And this is my impossible part. I have tried `.parent()` `.closest` `.prev()` but it all gives me nothing (nothing that I would like). That's my js code, the one I am testing:

```
if($('input').prop('checked')) {
    $(this).parent('li').css('color','red');
}
```

Comment: Where are you including that JS code? You would (probably) want it to be in a click handler on each checkbox. Is the idea to find the checkbox that is already checked, or to respond when the user clicks the checkbox?

Comment: I am including it in the document without handler yet. My goal is that the :checked when i click Remove(button) will delete its <li>. I havent get that far, I was trying to test it first thats why I have some default checked and why I have the jquery code in the (document).ready, so I can test if the code checked-->its parent <li>-->colorRed works. If that works I will have a union between the status of the checkbox and the <li> i want to delete next. Does it make sense?

Comment: Could you please post the context of the JavaScript snippet? What does `this` refer to? You might think `$(this)` will refer to the input, but it probably won't, depending on the surrounding jQuery usage.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` has nothing to do with the checked input in your code. It is most likely the window object, it does not magically get the context of what you selected above.

Other issue is you are not looking for the checked input, you are selecting all of the inputs and when you read the prop, it is selecting the first input from the list, it is not checking them all for a checked input.

So you need to change your selector, you need to use each and now the `this` would be the input element that is checked.

```
$('input:checked').each(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').css('color','red');
});
```

And this needs to be run on document ready or after the elements are rendered on the page. And there is no need for the each, just showing you the this, you can just chain the calls.

```
$('input:checked').parent('li').css('color','red');
```

And please learn about the label element.

Comment: wow thanks! that was great, it worked! Thanks for explaining me the difference bt this and each().

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look at your code:

```
// `.prop` does not select elements,
// it returns a property of an element,
// therefore whether the first <input>
// on the page is checked.
if($('input').prop('checked')) {
    // `this` likely does not refer to anything useful
    // Usually, it's only safe to use `$(this)` in `.each`
    // and event handlers.
    $(this).parent('li').css('color','red');
}
```

I think you want something like this ([check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7s5to1q/)):

```
// Query for all <input>s which are checked
$('input:checked')
// Select their <li> parents
.parent('li')
// Apply CSS (or do whatever you want, e.g. remove())
.css('color','red');
```

Comment: Thanks, it is great. Really. I was messing around and complicating things. This was a great experience as my first post.

Answer (score -1):

First, if you are trying to check the condition on the document.ready, you'll have to find that input which is already selected, without giving the name parameter, checked will not work properly.

your above code will work after giving some event handlers.

Comment: But if for example, instead of       $(this).parent('li').css('color','red');        I write      $('ul').css('color','red');      it will print the <ul> in red, so I believe its detecting it. You mean if I specify the name parameter the $(this).parent('li') will find what I am looking for?